# docker container monitoring using collectd

Tags: docker, puppet

we want to publish docker container metrics data using collectd, and below mentioned is our puppet script (reference: https://github.com/cloudwatt/docker-collectd-plugin)

Here is our puppet snippet

```
collectd::plugin { 'collectd-docker-plugin' :
      plugin => 'docker',
      content => template('test-iops/dockerplugin.erb'),
  }
```

And here is dockerplugin.erb

LoadPlugin python

```
<Plugin python>
  ModulePath "/usr/sbin/collectd"
  Import "dockerplugin"

  <Module dockerplugin>
    BaseURL "unix://var/run/docker.sock"
  </Module>
</Plugin>
```

collectd log message is

```
plugin_load: Could not find plugin "docker" from /usr/lib64/collectd
```

Comment: Are you certain that there isn't another section of your collectd configuration that references a `docker` plugin?

Comment: we are using puppet to create collectd and add plugin. There is no other section that reference docker plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that there is no `docker` plugin per-se for CollectD. the `docker-collectd-plugin` is a Python-based plugin.

Try with:

```
collectd::plugin { 'collectd-docker-plugin':
  plugin  => 'python',
  content => template('test-iops/dockerplugin.erb'),
}
```

By doing this, you also don't need to put `LoadPlugin python` in your `.erb` file; I believe that Puppet snippet will do that for you already (although it doesn't hurt if it's there twice).

May I also suggest using the plugin version from https://github.com/lebauce/docker-collectd-plugin, which seems to be the "true" upstream repository. I just happened to have contributed a whole bunch of fixes and improvements for it!